Output thruster forces from a gazebo simulation with the thruster plugins
I am using a thruster plugin with gazebo, and I am trying to output the total force from all thrusters that I have in the body fixed frame. I was hoping to be pointed to where the calculation happens that uses the input thruster force and the location and roll pitch yaw position of each thruster to compute a thrust force in the body fixed frame. The ThrusterPlugin.cc and ThrusterROSPlugin.cc files both give a thruster force that is in the thruster frame so I assume there is code that uses that value to compute force that influences the motions of the vehicle.
